# How does Qt's Wizard registerField, setField, and field methods work?

Tags: c++, qt, wizard

I have a class inherited from `QWizardPage`, which registers its widgets using `registerField()`.

```
QLineEdit* input = new QLineEdit;
input->setText("Hello");
QLineEdit* output = new QLineEdit;

QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout;
layout->addRow("Input", input);
layout->addRow("Output", output);
setLayout(layout);

registerField("input", input);
registerField("output", output);
```

I then expected to be able to get and set the values using `field()` and `setField()`, but I can't get it to work.

```
setField("output", field("input"));
```

This does *not* set the text property of the output `QLineEdit`. Any ideas what the problem is? (My understanding probably, but why doesn't it work?). `field("input")` returns a `QVariant` with unspecified type (I expected the `"Hello"` string to be returned.

Complete code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QWizard>
#include <QWizardPage>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFormLayout>

class MyWizard : public QWizard
{
public:
   MyWizard();
};

class MyWizardPage : public QWizardPage
{
public:
   MyWizardPage();
};

MyWizardPage::MyWizardPage()
{
   QLineEdit* input = new QLineEdit;
   input->setText("Hello");
   QLineEdit* output = new QLineEdit;

   QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout;
   layout->addRow("Input", input);
   layout->addRow("Output", output);
   setLayout(layout);

   registerField("input", input);
   registerField("output", output);
   setField("output", field("input"));
}

MyWizard::MyWizard()
{
   addPage(new MyWizardPage);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   QApplication application(argc, argv);
   MyWizard wizard;
   return wizard.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried and `field("input").toString()` returns an empty string. So I'd say it's not that the wizard isn't setting the string, but that it's getting it always empty. Why? I have no clue.

Comment: I was just wondering if you managed to resolve this problem since I am facing tha same issue.

Answer (score 1):

According the [QWizardPage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qwizardpage.html#registerField) documentation when you register a field with QLineEdit, the textChanged() SIGNAL is included by default. That means that every time you write in a QLineEdit, it's field value will update automatically. In your code you just need to use field("input").toString() to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new items on page and use `registerField()` function in `QWizardPage` constructor. Then outside you can use `field()` and `setField()`. Using these functions in `QWizardPage` constructor is not logical as you can access your new items (`input` and `output`).

To check functions `field()` and `setField()` just try to use it after `wizard` creation:

```
MyWizard wizard;
wizard.setField("output", field("input"));
```